# Kotlin generic constraints - require param to be of same type as other

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I have a set of two pojo's like so:

```
data class Test (
    var id : Long? = null
)

data class TestOther (
    var id : Long = 0,
    var isCool : Boolean = false
}
```

and then I have an infix function like so:

```
infix fun <T : Any?> KProperty<T>.equal(rhs : KProperty<T>) = BinaryExpression<Boolean>(this, rhs, EQUALS)
```

then this works fine as I'd expect:

```
Test::id equal TestOther::id
```

but so does this, since T is all types that extend Any?:

```
Test::id equal TestOther::isCool
```

Is there anyway to specify generic constraints such that nullable and non nullable types can be compared, but objects of different types cannot without having to specify an overload for every possible concrete type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to do right now. You may follow the issue for more details
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13198

I see a workaround here (similar to the one from the issue). The idea is to wrap the `KProperty<R>` into a wrapper class without variance. As you see, the `KProperty` type has `out R` variance, which works against us in the example. You may follow the link for the details on the declaration-side variance in Kotlin
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance

The workaround works as strict as expected

```
class KWrapper<R>(val p : KProperty<R>)
infix fun <T : KWrapper<R>, R> T.equal(rhs : T) = false
val <T> KProperty<T>.wrap get() = KWrapper(this)

val a = Test::id.wrap equal TestOther::id.wrap //fails: Long vs Long?
val b = Test::id.wrap equal Test::id.wrap //works
val c = Test::id.wrap equal TestOther::isCool.wrap // fails Long vs Boolean
```

The downside is that you need to use `.wrap` extension property (or extension function) for the left and right parameters separately

Comment: It's cool that the language can produce such an elegant type safe workaround, but annoying that I have to use language features to work around this. Is there no plan to allow overwriting declaration site variance with use-site notation, for when a use site should demand invariance upon a covariant type during type inference? Also, in my specific case, I wanted non-nullable and nullable types to be accepted (both a and b). Is that possible? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Eugene_Petrenko I found that if I declare my infix function as such from your example ```infix fun <T : KWrapper<out R>, R> T.equal(rhs : T) = false``` with the out prefix, it infers to most common ancestor of Long? and Long, which is Long?, so that suits my needs well enough (accepts case a and b, but rejects c).